# Using tabletools with AdminLTE in Laravel

Tags: datatables, laravel-5, tabletools, adminlte

I finally used AdminLTE and got datatables to work, but now I want to add tabletools also.

I installed using [this](https://github.com/acacha/adminlte-laravel)

1. laravel new laravel-with-admin-lte
2. cd laravel-with-admin-lte
3. adminlte-laravel install

Then I edited the `scripts.blade.php` to add the scripts (not sure if this is correct but it works:

```
<script src="{{ asset('/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/plugins/datatables/extensions/TableTools/dataTables.tableTools.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
  $(function () {
    $("#example2").DataTable();
    $('#example1').DataTable({
      "paging": true,
      "lengthChange": false,
      "searching": true,
      "ordering": true,
      "info": true,
      "autoWidth": false,
      "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "tableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "/plugins/datatables/extensions/TableTools/swf/copy_csv_xls.swf"}
    });
  });
</script>
```

Then I added the following to my `htmlheader.blade.php` to include css:

```
<link href="{{ asset('/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="{{ asset('/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I want to be able to see the export options (xls,csv etc).

Should I add something to show these links (buttons) or is something wrong with how I implented tabletools?

---

Also tried to change:

```
"/plugins/datatables/extensions/TableTools/swf/copy_csv_xls.swf"
```

into

```
"../TableTools/swf/copy_csv_xls.swf"
```

**Problem:**

I don't see the buttons or links for exporting.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I would recommend you add it as a plugin in the config/adminlte.php.
See documentation:
https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE/wiki/Plugins-Configuration.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).